# Extracting images from video in JRuby-1.7.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, video-processing

I want to extract images from a m4v video sent from mobile to my rails server. These images will be later used for face recognization purposes. There is a gem called "[streamio-ffmpeg](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg)" that does this job nicely and easily but the problem is that it does not support JRuby-1.7.13 that I am currently using on my server. It's a big application and upgrading the JRuby version not desirable at this moment.

Can someone please suggest JRuby1.7.13 compatible alternative solutions/gems to extract the images from a video file?

Comment: It looks like it's just a wrapper for ffmpeg. Can't you see what the needed ffmpeg command is, and write it directly?

Comment: Thanks @EricDuminil. Could you please suggest native ffmpeg commands to extract N frames specifying custom frame rate (for example 6/2) from a video of any length? In streamio-ffmpeg, we can do this with code:
`movie.screenshot("screenshot_%d.jpg", { vframes: 50, frame_rate: '6/2' }, validate: false)`

(50 is number of frames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [sourcecode](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg/blob/master/lib/ffmpeg/transcoder.rb#L74), it looks like `streamio-ffmpeg` outputs the underlying command by default :

```
FFMPEG.logger.info("Running transcoding...\n#{command}\n")
```

So all you have to do is execute :

```
movie.screenshot("screenshot_%d.jpg", { vframes: 50, frame_rate: '6/2' }, validate: false)
```

on a system where `streamio-ffmpeg` is installed.

You look at the output, extract the command, and use it somewhere else with :

```
system("ffmpeg arguments_you_extracted_from_the_logs")
```

without having to install `streamio-ffmpeg`.

Comment: Thanks @EricDuminil. Your reply was helpful. This ffmpeg command did the job: `"ffmpeg -y -i my_input_file.mp4 -vframes 50 -f \"image2\" output_file_%d"`